# How to do thick underline or draw rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm attempting to draw a think underline underneith my header about 10-15 px thick. I've tried adding a picture box and then drawing to that, but it's not being drawn to the screen. Is there a better way to do this, or a way to make my method work?

Thanks!

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            Pen selPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            g.DrawRectangle(selPen, 0, 0, 700, 15);
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I searched the toolbox a bit more, and I found a RectangleShape thing which did just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A common trick for having thick lines in WinForms is to create a `Label` with `BorderStyle` set to `FixedSingle` (you can experiment with other borders) and `Height = 1` (`Width` as appropriate). You can draw all this in the designer, or try to use some other "degenerate" controls - `Panel` with appropriate visual settings.

Other options are of course using a custrom `UserControl` or handling/overriding the [`OnPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) event and drawing on the graphics provided by the [`Control.CreateGraphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method (no need to put `PictureBox` on the form).

Comment: I tried the label with BorderStyle set to FixedSingle and Height=1, but it just gave me a 1 or 2px thick line, not the 10-15px thick line I need. If I were to use the CreateGraphics method, where would I put this code? I've tried using code I've found in different posts but it never does anything...

Comment: Try a `Panel` then - it can be as thick as you want. As for drawing - put the code in the `OnPaint` event.

Comment: @user2856410 I've updated the answer also with the link to the `OnPaint` event description. There is a drawing example there. The first one draws directly on the `Form`, without the `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you cannon draw in from 1 load event. Place your code into another event or in a button and it will work fine.

Comment: Where would I put code I'd like to be executed right when the program starts then?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CreateGraphics() as it is a **temporary** surface that gets erased when the form refreshes.

Instead, handle the Paint() event of your Form/Control and use the supplied `e.Graphics` to draw with.